# ComboBox doesn't populate with data in Silverlight MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

Well i don't know what to do else. I've checked in the code and everything it's looking fine.

So my problem is that the combo box isn't populated with any data, I've checked the ObservableCollection set and it has the data but it isn't any popualted

I used the MVVM pattern and everything goes well but the GET isn't called

Could i get some tip what could be the cause, because i'm out of ideas

StudentDetailView.xaml

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="176" Width="376">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="31*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <sdk:Label Content="Clasa ID:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" 
                  Name="clasaIDComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Nume" 
                  SelectedValuePath="ID" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Data Nasterii:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <sdk:DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="data_NasteriiDatePicker" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
        <sdk:Label Content="ID:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="iDTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Liceu ID:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="liceuIDTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Nume:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="numeTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />

    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Save Student" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,232,0,0" Name="btnSaveStudent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Click="btnSaveStudent_Click" />
    <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,232,0,0" Name="btnCancelStudent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnCancelStudent_Click" />
    <ct:ValidationSummary Width="300" Margin="12,194,70,23" />
</Grid>
```

StudentDetailView.xaml.cs

```
public StudentDetailView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        clasaIDComboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("LstHighSchool"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
        clasaIDComboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedHighSchool"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError = true, ValidatesOnExceptions = true });
}
```

And partial code from StudentViewModel.cs

```
        private void AddNewStudentView(object param)
    {
        StudentDetailView addNewStudentView = new StudentDetailView();
        addNewStudentView.DataContext = new Student();
        var sdfsdfj = new StudentViewModel();

         LoadOperation<Liceu> li = DomainContext.Load(DomainContext.GetLiceusQuery());
        li.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            LstHighSchool = (s as LoadOperation<Liceu>).Entities.ToObservableCollection();
        };

        addNewStudentView.Closed += delegate
        {
            if (addNewStudentView.DialogResult == true)
            {
                Student newStudent = addNewStudentView.DataContext as Student;



                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newStudent.Nume))
                {
                    newStudent.ValidationErrors.Add(new ValidationResult("Numele nu poate sa fie invalid",new string[]{"Nume"}));
                }
                if (!newStudent.LiceuID.HasValue)
                {
                    newStudent.ValidationErrors.Add(new ValidationResult("Liceu ID este gol", new string[] { "LiceuID" }));
                }

                if (!newStudent.HasValidationErrors)
                {


                    if (newStudent != null)
                    {
                        DomainContext.Students.Add(newStudent);
                        LstStudents.Add(newStudent);

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    addNewStudentView.Show();

                }
            }

        };

        addNewStudentView.Show();
        OnPropertyChanged("LstHighSchool");


    }
    private bool CanWork(object param)
    {
        return true; //for the moment this remains true, cause you can add all the time a new student, but this can be changed if there must be some conditions

    }

    private ObservableCollection<Liceu> _lstHighSchool;
    public ObservableCollection<Liceu> LstHighSchool
    {
        get
        {
            return _lstHighSchool;
        }
        set
        {
            _lstHighSchool = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LstHighSchool");
        }
    }

    private int _selectedHighSchool;
    public int SelectedHighSchool
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedHighSchool;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedHighSchool = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedHighSchool");
        }
    }



    #endregion
```

Comment: You could post only the code where you have the issue!

Comment: Why are you defining bindings from C# code and not XAML? Also your MVVM way of doing things looks really broken as you're currently instantiating and manipulating views from what you called a ViewModel.

Comment: @Sajeetharan the problem i think is from ViewModel because the Get isn't called

Comment: @ken2k I'm still a newbie in MVVM, i'm defining binding in C# code to separate design from code binding in case of changes.

Comment: `Grid DataContext="{Binding}"` what context is there at this point? Check your output window for message about binding--if there was an issue binding, it will say it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Get rid of the `Grid DataContext="{Binding}"` and then your combobox in the xaml should look like:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="Nume" 
                  SelectedValuePath="ID" ItemsSource="{Binding LstHighSchool}" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedHighSchool}" />
```

Secondly, your code behind for the View should look like,

```
public StudentDetailView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext= new StudentViewModel();
}
```

Lastly, in the StudentViewModel.cs there should be a property called `LstHighSchool` which looks fine.

Comment: Thank you so so much, that was my problem. And besides that i found out that i was changing the datacontext in 2 places. 1 In the viewmodel and after that in the view.

What is the best practice for instantiating and manipulating views ? I should work with them in the view or in the viewmodel ? 

Thank you

Comment: I have instantiated Views in the Respective ViewModel, which was good, since the ViewModel got to decide which View to use.

But instantiating the ViewModel in the code behind (like you are doing here) of the View is convenient too, but then you have an instance of VM in the View, which I think is not so MVVM-ish..

Comment: Thank you, i need to read more about MVVM and patterns. Thank you again !